# I have two separate objects that I'd like to use either to refer & align with, except when I enter wireframe this hides the shape I wish to refer to

Tags: wireframe

I have two objects that are in different collections or layers idk (point is they dont merge with each other must access layout mode to work on either.

see title: 
"I have two separate objects that I'd like to use either to refer & align with, except when I enter wireframe this hides the shape I wish to refer to"

Comment: nvm, Just used hide face,

Comment: Realized problem the wire frame too dark against a dark picture

Comment: found this great theme solve https://blenderartists.org/t/theme-neutral-theme-for-blender-2-8/1137449

Answer (score 0):

found epic theme to see better:
https://blenderartists.org/t/theme-neutral-theme-for-blender-2-8/1137449

had dark image and a dark theme. oops